# Listen for Vaadin web app shutting down — What is the ending lifecycle equivalent of VaadinServiceInitListener class?

Tags: web-applications, vaadin, exit, lifecycle, vaadin-flow

When a [*Vaadin Flow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) web app is launching, we can register our implementation of [`VaadinServiceInitListener`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.5/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServiceInitListener.html) to be automatically instantiated via [SPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface). In that listener, we can implement a method [`serviceInit`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.5/com/vaadin/flow/server/VaadinServiceInitListener.html#serviceInit-com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceInitEvent-) which receives a [`ServiceInitEvent`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.5/com/vaadin/flow/server/ServiceInitEvent.html) as the web app is starting up. This process is [explained well in the manual](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-service-init-listener.html).

➥ What is the equivalent for the web app shutting down?

➥ Where does one perform tear-down and clean-up work as the Vaadin app is ending?

I know how to do this at the [Java/Jakarta Servlet](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/) level, underneath Vaadin. We write a class implementing the [`ServletContextListener`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) interface. In that class, we implement the `contextInitialized` method to be invoked when the web app launches. And we implement the `contextDestroyed` method when the web app is exiting. Since Vaadin offers an abstraction of this for launching, I thought perhaps Vaadin also offers an abstraction for the exiting.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any dedicated SPI for listening to shutdowns. Instead, you can use the same VaadinServiceInitListener SPI and through that register a `ServiceDestroyListener` with the `VaadinService` instance.

The code for doing this would thus be something like this:

```
public class MyServiceListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {
  @Override
  public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
    VaadinService service = event.getSource();
    service.addServiceDestroyListener(destroyEvent -> {
      System.out.println("Destroy event for service " + destroyEvent.getSource());
    });
  }
}
```